# Algorithm to check availability with two time frames

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What would be the best algorithm to check the availability of a device for rental with two time frames?

I have the timeframe of the device and the existing rental (start & end date) and the timeframe of the "new" rental.

Example:

```
New rental: 18 April 2013 - 25 April 2013
```

In this cases I'd like to return false:

```
a) Existing rental: 20 April 2013 - 24 April 2013
b) Existing rental: 16 April 2013 - 24 April 2013
c) Existing rental: 20 April 2013 - 28 April 2013
d) Existing rental: 16 April 2013 - 28 April 2013
```

There could be even more cases but I think it's clear what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a good Data Structure or some logics. Hope the logic below can filter out all overlapping time frames.

```
 var overlappingIntervals = intervals
                    .Where(r => 
                        (r.Start <= toCheck.Start && r.End >= toCheck.End) //inside a timeframe
                    || (r.Start >= toCheck.Start && r.End <= toCheck.End) //other is inside our timeframe
                    || (r.Start >= toCheck.Start && r.End >= toCheck.End && r.Start <=toCheck.End) //end overlap
                    || (r.Start <= toCheck.Start && r.End <= toCheck.End && r.End >= toCheck.Start)// start overlap

                    ).ToList();
```

I have also placed commnets to detect conditions.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateInterval> intervals = new List<DateInterval>();
            intervals.Add(new DateInterval(Convert.ToDateTime("26 April 2013"), Convert.ToDateTime("27 April 2013")));
            intervals.Add(new DateInterval(Convert.ToDateTime("16 April 2013"), Convert.ToDateTime("24 April 2013")));
            intervals.Add(new DateInterval(Convert.ToDateTime("20 April 2013"), Convert.ToDateTime("28 April 2013")));
            intervals.Add(new DateInterval(Convert.ToDateTime("16 April 2013"), Convert.ToDateTime("28 April 2013")));

            DateInterval toCheck = new DateInterval(Convert.ToDateTime("16 April 2013"),
                                                    Convert.ToDateTime("25 April 2013"));

            var overlappingIntervals = intervals
                .Where(r => 
                    (r.Start <= toCheck.Start && r.End >= toCheck.End) //inside a timeframe
                || (r.Start >= toCheck.Start && r.End <= toCheck.End) //other is inside our timeframe
                || (r.Start >= toCheck.Start && r.End >= toCheck.End && r.Start <=toCheck.End) //end overlap
                || (r.Start <= toCheck.Start && r.End <= toCheck.End && r.End >= toCheck.Start)// start overlap

                ).ToList();
            Console.Write(overlappingIntervals.Count);

        }
    }


    public class DateInterval
    {

        public DateInterval(DateTime Start, DateTime End)
        {
            this.Start = Start;
            this.End = End;
        }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you can use the same logic you are using some DB like SQL to store timeframes

Comment: I want to do it with C#.
Your solution looks good, Shoaib Shaikh. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, presumably you want to check whether any existing rental intersects with the new rental.

Firstly, you need to decide exactly what "intersect" means. Given that you've given *date* values (rather than date/time values) I suggest that your date ranges are probably inclusive at both ends (e.g. April 20th - April 22nd includes April 22nd, so would intersect with April 22nd - April 24th).

Next, you want to get a suitable representation - I'm biased, but I'd suggest [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) as it has a representation for "just a date" rather than "a date and time". You may then want to add something like `DateInterval` as a composite type.

Third, I'd strongly recommend drawing out on paper the possibilities. Draw two lines, one for the existing rental and one for the new rental, and work out all the possibilities. I *suspect* you actually want just something like:

```
public sealed class DateInterval
{
    private readonly LocalDate start;
    private readonly LocalDate end;

    // TODO: Properties

    public DateInterval(LocalDate start, LocalDate end)
    {
        // TODO: Assert that end >= start, and that they use the same
        // calendar system
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public bool IntersectsWith(DateInterval other)
    {
        // It intersects *unless* it's either completely before or completely
        // after *other*. There are other ways of representing this, but it's
        // the way that makes most intuitive sense to me.
        return !(this.end < other.start || this.start > other.end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to check the availability of time frames:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void CheckAvailableTmeFrame()
{
  TimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2013, 4, 20 ), new DateTime( 2013, 4, 24 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2013, 4, 16 ), new DateTime( 2013, 4, 24 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2013, 4, 20 ), new DateTime( 2013, 4, 28 ) ) );
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2013, 4, 16 ), new DateTime( 2013, 4, 26 ) ) );

  // test period
  TimeRange test = new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2013, 4, 18 ), new DateTime( 2013, 4, 25 ) );

  // find the available 
  TimeGapCalculator<TimeRange> gapCalculator = new TimeGapCalculator<TimeRange>();
   ITimePeriodCollection gaps = gapCalculator.GetGaps( periods, test );

  Console.WriteLine( "Time frame {0}. Available: {1}", 
     test, gaps.Count == 1 && gaps[ 0 ].Equals( test ) );
} // CheckAvailableTmeFrame
```